# Drop dataframe columns where rows value is like '[ ]'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe there are few rows in which the value is like "[]" and I want to drop the whole column, how to get it done?

[Data Frame Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7dTi.png)
And Here's my code

```
import re

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for j, column in row.iteritems():
      #print(column)
      #print(j)
      t = re.findall("\[\]", column)
      if t:
        df.drop(j, axis=1, inplace=True)
      else:
        print('Nothing'+j)
```

and here's the error I get

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-927572386a36> in <module>
      3     #print(column)
      4     #print(j)
----> 5         t = re.findall("\[\]", column)
      6         if t:
      7             df.drop(j, axis=1, inplace=True)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/re.py in findall(pattern, string, flags)
    221 
    222     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 223     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
    224 
    225 def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: Do you need remove columns if all values are `[]` in column or at least one value `[]` in columns?

Comment: at least one value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need cast values to boolean and filter only `True`s columns with [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[], [], ['d']],
                   'b':[['d'], ['a'], ['d']],
                   'c':[[], [], []]})

print (df)
     a    b   c
0   []  [d]  []
1   []  [a]  []
2  [d]  [d]  []

df1 = df.loc[:, df.astype(bool).all()]
print (df1)
     b
0  [d]
1  [a]
2  [d]
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.astype(bool))
       a     b      c
0  False  True  False
1  False  True  False
2   True  True  False
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, can you please explain how does this work?

Comment: `df.astype(bool)` converts the dataframe to `bool`. Empty list will be converted to `False` . Then `df.loc[:, df.astype(bool).all()]` selects all columns in which all values are not `False`